# Allocating 2D array of dimensions read from file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c89

I would like to read 2 numbers `n,m` from text file and then allocate a 2D array with `n` rows and `m` columns.

Also, I would like to initialise the array in my `main` function in order to use it later in other functions, and do the reading and allocating in a different function, which I will call from the `main` function.

I know how to handle the reading, but I'm struggling with the array allocation.

I've read quite a few answer to similar questions here, but they didn't help me.

I've wrote the following code, but not sure how to continue with it to get the desired result:

```
void func(int** array, int* rows, int* cols){
  int n, m;
  FILE *file;
  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
    /* reading numbers n and m */
    *rows = n;
    *cols = m;
    **array = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    fclose(file);
  }
}

int main() {      
  int rows, cols;
  int** array;
  func(&array, &rows, &cols);
  return 0;
}
```

I thought perhaps I should first allocate a 2D array with `calloc` and then use `realloc` after reading `n,m`, but not sure if that's the best practise.

*What is the best practise to allocate a 2D array based on dimensions I read from text file?*

Comment: What is this: &&array

Comment: @machine_1Would like to pass a pointer to the array.

Comment: @Itay4 What is the question?

Comment: You cannot allocate for the parameter `int **array` in `func` without **returning** the newly allocated pointer for assignment in the caller. `func` receives a **copy of the pointer** (with its very own and very different address than `array` in `main()`). In order to allocate without providing a return, then you must pass the **address of** `array` (e.g. the parameter must be `func (int ***array, *rows, *cols)` and call it as `func (&array, &rows, &cols)`, you must allocate both pointers and storage for `m` integers per-pointer. (note: becoming a *3-Star Programmer* in C isn't a compliment)

Comment: @DataChanturia The question is what is the best practise to allocate a 2D array based on dimensions I read from text file.

Comment: @4386427 Sorry, added the tag.

Answer (score 3):

First the biggest goofs here:

- Your function doesn't have any *types* in the function signature -- this should be rejected by the compiler
- a 2D array is **not** the same as an *array of pointers*
- what should `&&` mean? `&` is the *address of* something, its result can't have an address because it isn't stored anywhere, so this doesn't make sense

If you want to dynamically allocate a real 2D array, you need to either have the second dimension fixed or use VLAs (which are optional in C11, but assuming support is quite safe) with a variable. Something like this:

```
// dimensions in `x` and `y`, should be of type `size_t`
int (*arr)[x] = malloc(y * sizeof *arr);
```

In any case, the second dimension is part of the type, so your structure won't work -- the calling code has to know this second dimension for passing a valid pointer.

---

**Hint:** This first part doesn't apply to the question any more, OP forgot to mention he's interested in C90 only. I added the appropriate tag, but leave the upper part of the answer for reference. The following applies to C90 as well:

---

You write `int **` in your code, this would be a pointer to a pointer. You can create something that can be **used** like a 2D array by using a pointer to a pointer, but then, you can't allocate it as a single chunk.

The outer pointer will point to an array of pointers (say, the "row-pointers"), so for each of these pointers, you have to allocate an array of the actual values. This could look like the following:

```
// dimensions again `x` and `y`
int **arr = malloc(y * sizeof *arr);
for (size_t i = 0; i < y; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(x * sizeof **arr);
}
```

Note on both snippets these are minimal examples. For real code, **you have to check the return value of `malloc()` each time**. It could return a *null pointer* on failure.

---

If you want to have a contiguous block of memory *in the absence of VLAs*, there's finally the option to just use a regular array and calculate indices yourself, something like:

```
int *arr = malloc(x * y * sizeof *arr);

// access arr[8][15] when x is the second dimension:
arr[x*8 + 15] = 24;
```

This will generate (roughly) the same executable code as a real 2D array, but of course doesn't look that nice in your source.

---

Note this is not much more than a direct answer to your immediate question. Your code contains more goofs. You should really enable a sensible set of compiler warnings (e.g. with `gcc` or `clang`, use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11` flags) and then fix each and every warning you get when you move on with your project.

Comment: You might point out he declares `int rows, cols;` and passes `&rows, &cols` and `func` properly takes `int *rows, int *cols` (the *address of* and `int` becomes a pointer parameter) -- so why does he think the declaration `int **array` and then (attempting...) to pass the *address of* `array` would require an `int **` parameter? Where did the additional level of indirection vanish to? (you can also scold a bit about enabling compiler warnings `;)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you're right, but this code is so riddled with errors, I decided it's best just to answer the immediate question. Will add a hint about warnings though in the hope they help to find/debug other goofs as well.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using ISO C90, so I can't use VLA, and since I don't know the size of 2nd dimension, how can I do what you suggested?

Comment: @Itay4 two options: Actually use a pointer-to-pointer type (this is shown as second alternative in this answer) -- or, use a flat array of size `x*y` and calculate the row-indexes yourself when accessing it (which results in basically the same compiled code as a real 2D-array, but takes more work to write).

Comment: @Itay4 - you are fine declaring `int **array`, and then allocating pointers and storage for `m` ints per-pointer -- but you have to figure out how to get the pointer to the beginning of your newly allocated `array` in `func` back to `main()`. You handle `rows` and `cols` correctly -- what is the stumbling block you are having seeing how `array` should be handled?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure I understand your second solution.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for the example. I've meant the second solution in the answer, not in the comment. Could you please elaborate on that? Not sure I understand where it goes, in `func`? If so, how do I pass the array to it?

Comment: @Itay4 please don't make this a [**chameleon question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). You asked about allocation with only the C tag, which normally means "newest standard". Now it's about C90, fine. But now you start asking about passing pointers. If you have further doubts, please take the time to ask a new, well-written question. I suggest you try it yourself first and read some generic resources on C and pointers.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sorry, but I didn't mean to do that. My original question was supposed to be on both, allocation and passing pointer to the array. I did try for quite a while to find an answer before posting this question. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @Itay4 if you want to do the allocation in a function, the most natural way for me would be to `return` the pointer from this function instead of passing it something. But I really think you should figure out what suits your program structure. Suggested reading topics: *pass-by-reference*, *pass-by-value* and how to "simulate" *pass-by-reference* in C (-> use pointers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176930/discussion-between-itay4-and-felix-palmen).